# How to change the product detail page to a 2 column layout in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, layout, product-page

I have created a layout XML file for a custom theme which inherits from the default Magento Blank theme:

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

and set the layout to 2columns-left:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
</page>
```

Also the setting under: "Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Layout" doesn't seem to have any effect.

Magento version: 2.3.2 CE

Comment: you run all command and apply permission

Comment: yes, I've run all commands and permissions are properly set. The site is in development mode, all caches are disabled, except the configuration cache. All layout changes in catalog_product_view.xml are working (moving and removing elements), except setting it to a two column layout.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to catalog_product_view.xml , you are required to create 2columns-left.xml 
Path will be `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/default/Magento_Theme/templates/2columns-left.xml` .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="2columns-left"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Upgrade and deploy static file after these changes.